# Выполнение запроса на смену типа поля, когда в базе 26 млн записей

Tags: mysql

Такой запрос выполняется около 6 часов, когда в таблице 26 млн записей. Можно ли как-то ускорить его или по частям выполнять?

```
ALTER TABLE `tasks_done` CHANGE `type` `type`TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
```

Comment: зачем ускорять? на ночь ставишь (как фильм) и идешь спать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По частям можно, но это будет значительно дольше, так как изменить тип по частям в пределах одной таблицы нельзя.

Создаете новую таблицу с правильными полями(и типами полей), называете ее `tasks_done_new`.
Копируете в нее блоками по 50 тыс строк(юзайте limit). информацию из основной таблицы. Это и есть разбиение.
Удаляете основную таблицу(drop). 
Переименовываете `tasks_done_new` в `tasks_done`.
Готово.

Рассчетное время простоя системы равно времени удаления старой tasks_done.

UPDATE:
Возможно, будет быстрее добавить новую колонку в старую таблицу, а потом удалить старую колонку и переименовать только что созданную.
Плюсы:

- пожалеете винчестер.

Минусы:

- могут навернуться запросы без указания конкретных колонок.
- может оказаться дольше, чем пересоздать таблицу.